# Download rtmp stream

Tags: macos, rtmp

Hi a friend of ours mother just passed and they'd like the recording of the wedding so they can keep it on a flash drive. I played for about a half hour but have been unsuccessful. After looking at the pages source I fount the following javascript

```
if ( hasProductInstall && !hasRequestedVersion ) {
                        // DO NOT MODIFY THE FOLLOWING FOUR LINES
                        // Location visited after installation is complete if installation is required
                        var MMPlayerType = (isIE == true) ? "ActiveX" : "PlugIn";
                        var MMredirectURL = window.location;
                        document.title = document.title.slice(0, 47) + " - Flash Player Installation";
                        var MMdoctitle = document.title;

                        AC_FL_RunContent(
                            "src", "http://AbrahamLGreenandSonSympathyNet.ezwebcast.com/player/playerProductInstall",
                            "FlashVars", "MMredirectURL="+MMredirectURL+'&MMplayerType='+MMPlayerType+'&MMdoctitle='+MMdoctitle+"",
                            "width", "483",
                            "height", "416",
                            "align", "middle",
                            "id", "FlashPlayer",
                            "allowFullScreen","true",
                            "quality", "high",
                            "bgcolor", "#FFFFFF",
                            "name", "FlashPlayer",
                            "allowScriptAccess","always",
                            "type", "application/x-shockwave-flash",
                            "pluginspage", "http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"
                        );
                    } else if (hasRequestedVersion) {
                        // if we've detected an acceptable version
                        // embed the Flash Content SWF when all tests are passed
                        AC_FL_RunContent(
                                "src", "http://AbrahamLGreenandSonSympathyNet.ezwebcast.com/player/player",
                                "FlashVars","isDebug=0&mv=rtmp://fms35.ezwebcast.com/play/6/recorded_streams/3208/stream15989&user_id=32125&movie_id=14275",
                                "width", "483",
                                "height", "416",
                                "align", "middle",
                                "id", "FlashPlayer",
                                "allowFullScreen","true",
                                "quality", "high",
                                "bgcolor", "#FFFFFF",
                                "name", "FlashPlayer",
                                "allowScriptAccess","always",
                                "type", "application/x-shockwave-flash",
                                "pluginspage", "http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"
                        );
                    }
```

The line of interest at least in my opinion is `rtmp://fms35.ezwebcast.com/play/6/recorded_streams/3208/stream15989&user_id=32125&movie_id=14275` I'm assuming that's what I need to download however when I downloaded rtmpdump and tried to run it I get the following and I haven't been able to figure out how to load the library or get this stream downloaded. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
USERs-MacBook-Pro:Desktop user$ rtmpdump -r rtmp://fms35.ezwebcast.com/play/2/recorded_streams/3208/stream15989 -W "http://media.kelbymediagroup.com/players/player-4.6-licensed.swf" -o ./funeral.flv
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/librtmp.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/rtmpdump
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /usr/local/lib/librtmp.dylib: stat() failed with errno=13
    /usr/local/lib/librtmp.dylib: stat() failed with errno=13
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

Comment: Hopefully this is viewable to you http://pmarionbeitman32124.abrahamlgreenandsonsympathynet.ezwebcast.com/show_video/id/14275